# How to undo uploading files in code collab code review?

Tags: code-collaborator

I started a code review from the command line using

```
ccollab adddiffs new D:\Development\review\before D:\Development\review\after
```

I made changes to the code and then went to upload those changes to the review using:

```
ccollab adddiffs ask D:\Development\WRONGpath\before D:\Development\WRONGpath\after
```

code collab errored out saying there were no files to upload.  Okay, fine.  I fixed the path and redid the command with the correct path

```
ccollab adddiffs ask D:\Development\review\before D:\Development\review\after
```

I properly edited the list of files in the text file leaving all the original file names in there except files I did not want added to the review, but Code collab proceeded to add the files as new rather than as diffs to the original files.  I'm wondering how I can undo the last upload to the review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only possible to delete files if there aren't any comments or defects on them. If the files you want to remove is part of a changelist (which it probably is in this case) then your only option is to remove the whole changelist.

In the `Review Materials` section you'll see a Delete button next to each changelist. You may need to change the `View As` option to `Separate` in order to delete the changelist.